# Define command to act like \ifvar

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I'm trying to manipulate multiple boolean variables which are simply named `one`, `two`, `three`, etc. and since I'm using them with a counter, I have defined some commands to take a numerical input and handle the boolean values:

```
\newif\ifp@one@
\newif\ifp@two@
\newif\ifp@three@

\def\p@settrue@#1{
  \ifnum#1 =1 \p@one@true \else
  \ifnum#1 =2 \p@two@true \else
  \ifnum#1 =3 \p@three@true
  \fi\fi\fi}

\def\p@setfalse@#1{<same as with true>}

\def\p@if@#1{
  \ifnum#1 =1 \expandafter\ifp@one@ \else
  \ifnum#1 =2 \expandafter\ifp@two@ \else
  \ifnum#1 =3 \expandafter\ifp@three@
  \fi\fi\fi}
```

The first two commands work fine, so if I run `\p@settrue@1`, then `\ifp@one@` is now `true`.

The problem if with the third function, `\p@if@`: I can't get it to work.  I thought that it would simply be a matter of adding `\expandafter` before each `\ifp@<number>@` but this doesn't work.

Ideally, I was hoping to use it like

```
\p@if@1
   <do something>
\else
   <do something else>
\fi
```

Why does this not work?

---

I realize I can instead define

```
\def\p@if@#1#2#3{
  \ifnum#1 =1 \ifp@one@#2\else#3\fi \else
  \ifnum#1 =2 \ifp@two@#2\else#3\fi \else
  \ifnum#1 =3 \ifp@three@#2\else#3\fi 
  \fi\fi\fi}
```

which is a nice alternative, but I'm still curious why the code above fails.

Comment: This seems to call for `\ifcase`

Comment: I was about to make same remark as @egreg.  Besides, there is one thing I don’t understand: are `\ifp@one@`, etc., themselves conditionals?  If so, they aren’t properly nested.

Comment: I didn't know about `\ifcase`, but by the sounds of it, it only executres one branch, and ultimately, I still need to have the boolean variables defined somewhere and accessible.

Also, @GustavoMezzetti, that was a typo... I shall ammend that quickly.

Comment: Suppose the first `\ifnum` inside `\p@if@` evaluates to false: then TeX will skip subsequent tokens, _but_ tracking nested conditionals as it goes.  When it comes to `\ifp@one@`, it thinks: “this is a conditional, so the next `\else` I find will pertain to it”; and indeed, when the following `\else` comes along, it will be paired with the `\ifp@one@` just seen.  At this point, TeX and your intentions are already out of sync. :-)

Comment: By why does `\expandafter` not work in this case?

Comment: Because it is being skipped over, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a translation table from number to textual representation:

```
\catcode`@=11

\def\p@translate#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or one\or two\or three\fi
}
\def\p@settrue@#1{%
  \csname p@\p@translate{#1}@true\endcsname
}
\def\p@setfalse@#1{%
  \csname p@\p@translate{#1}@false\endcsname
}
\def\p@cond@#1{%
  TT\fi
  \csname ifp@\p@translate{#1}@\endcsname
}

\newif\ifp@one@
\newif\ifp@two@
\newif\ifp@three@

% Testing
\def\msg#{\immediate\write16}
\p@settrue@{1}
\if\p@cond@{1}\msg{1 = true}\else\msg{1 = false}\fi
\if\p@cond@{3}\msg{3 = true}\else\msg{3 = false}\fi

\bye
```

Since it's impossible to have a macro that behaves correctly like conditionals in skipped texts, the `TT\fi` trick is used, so you call

```
\if\p@cond@{1}%
  <text to be executed if conditional 1 is true>%
\else
  <text to be executed if conditional 1 is false>%
\fi
```

Output:

```
1 = true
3 = false
```

Comment: Very neat, and this can be quite naturally extended :)

Answer (score 6):

The definition of `\p@if@` does not work as expected, because of the nesting `\if` constructs. Much more of `\expandafter` are needed to clean up the closing `\else` and `\fi` tokens.

The following example uses a `\csname` construct to ease the clean up and changes the syntax. `\iftrue` precedes `\p@if@`. The latter is a macro and it is not recognized by TeX as part of the `\if` commands. When TeX skips over branches, then it does not inspect macros. The construct `\iftrue\p@if@` can also be used inside `\if` constructs.

```
\catcode`\@=11

\newif\ifp@one@
\newif\ifp@two@
\newif\ifp@three@

\def\p@settrue@#1{
  \ifcase#1\or
    \p@one@true\or
    \p@two@true\or
    \p@three@true
  \fi
}
\def\p@setfalse@#1{
  \ifcase#1\or
    \p@one@false\or
    \p@two@false\or
    \p@three@false
  \fi
}

\def\p@if@#1{%
  \fi
  \csname if%
    \ifcase#1false\or
      \ifp@one@ true\else false\fi\or
      \ifp@two@ true\else false\fi\or
      \ifp@three@ true\else false\fi\else
      false%
    \fi
  \endcsname
}

% Testing
\def\msg#{\immediate\write16}
\p@settrue@1
\iftrue\p@if@1\msg{1 = true}\else\msg{1 = false}\fi
\iftrue\p@if@3\msg{3 = true}\else\msg{3 = false}\fi

\csname @@end\endcsname\end
```

Result:

```
1 = true
3 = false
```